# Looping through files in Maven

Tags: maven, thrift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop through specific resource files in maven to generate sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903097/loop-through-specific-resource-files-in-maven-to-generate-sources)

Is there a way to loop through specific resources in maven?

I use maven-antrun-plugin to generates-sources based on Thrift IDL and I am not allowed to use maven-thrift-plugin. The maven plugin does not do wildcard replacement and I am looking for a simple way to specify all thrift files in resource directory to generate source.

Also once the sources are generated I want to copy to the source directory. I am not sure whether it is a good idea to copy the generated sources to the src directory. But I am creating a separate project for the generated sources, so all the code in the src directory will be generated and will form a jar. Right now I am using execution tasks (`<copy> </copy>`) as part of maven-antrun-plugin to do it but guess this is not the most elegant way. All the generated code gets checked in to source control.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try [maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) instead.